# How to select only the stroke in a transparent backgroud rectangle?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

How can i make a transparent rectangle selectable only when i click on the stroke? I tried two different approach as you can see from the snippet below, the object on the left is a rectangle with a transparent background, the object on the right is a group object with multiple lines. I want to know how to be able to select the element only when i click on the stroke, with both objects if you click on the inner transparent area the object becomes selected.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('a');
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  left: 10,
  top: 20,
  height: 160,
  width: 80,
  fill: 'transparent',
  stroke: 'red'
}));
var rectLine1 = new fabric.Line([0, 0, 80, 0], {
  stroke: 'red',
  left: 100,
  top: 20
});
var rectLine2 = new fabric.Line([0, 160, 0, 0], {
  stroke: 'red',
  left: 100,
  top: 20
});
var rectLine3 = new fabric.Line([0, 160, 0, 0], {
  stroke: 'red',
  left: 180,
  top: 20
});
let rectLine4 = new fabric.Line([0, 0, 80, 0], {
  stroke: 'red',
  left: 100,
  top: 180
});
var group = new fabric.Group([rectLine1, rectLine2, rectLine3, rectLine4], {
  left: 110,
  top: 20
})
canvas.add(group)
canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
.c {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="a" class="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that? I get a feeling that would make it significantly harder to select objects with thin strokes  ... educated guess, that would require refactoring for the core fabric code

Comment: my project requires that...however i just found that setting perPixelTargetFind: true on the object actually solve the problem

Comment: now i need a way to add some tolerance because as you said it's really hard to select objects with thin strokes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that setting `perPixelTargetFind: true` solves the problem, you can also set a tolerance on the canvas `targetFindTolerance: 10` to be able to select objects with thin strokes. I'll paste the working code below in case anyone needs it.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('a', {
  targetFindTolerance: 10
});
canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
  left: 10,
  top: 20,
  height: 160,
  width: 80,
  fill: 'transparent',
  stroke: 'red',
  perPixelTargetFind: true,
}));
canvas.renderAll();
```

```css
.c {
  border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.7.19/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="a" class="c" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```